# How to fetch geocode data from URL of maps API of google instead of adding geocode function in IONIC WebAPP?

Tags: javascript, api, cordova, ionic-framework

Okay so basically I used an Ionic natives forward for getting lat and lng of my input location. But as natives are only for Android and IOS, I want something API kind of thing which I can use in any platform and which will return me proper lat lang of location. 
After searching I came to there is URL Api of Google

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ term +'CA&sensor=false
```

So I tried using that. But while calling it through my code. It giving undefined input.

Here is my code:

```
getLocation(term){


return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ term +'CA&sensor=false')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.results[0]);
      resolve(data);
    });
});
```

}

Also I am calling it from another function like this :

```
    initMap() {

        this.getLocation('seattle');
        //Also I want to use lat lang here. Please provide proper way to get that.

}
```

How to use that URL Api in IONIC? and please don't provide any solution of using natives as I want to deploy this in only browser platform.

Comment: Does it work if you change the URL to this: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + term + ', +CA&sensor=false'?

Comment: no. still same issue. No output.

Comment: If I try your URL directly in my browser I get a warning my rate limit has been exceeded. Most likely this means you need to register an API key to increase your limit. To test this could you show the raw response of the request (before you parse it to JSON)?

Comment: I think google limited use on api key.. If I create new api key and use it once it will show the output.. but if I refresh the page it will show rate limiting. Can't we use google api key free for development purpose? like with watermark.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) guide explains how to retrieve an API key. [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing) page gives more info about the pricing. It appears billing info is an absolute requirement. There is a mention of a 200 Dollar monthly credit which might apply to you. I'd say give it a try and otherwise consider using another API if available.

Comment: another API? do u know any another source other than google?

Comment: Not of the top of my mind but I am sure a quick Google search will yield promising results :)